# How to simply run my executable after it was built?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I have this launch.json running. Pressing F5, it first executes my Makefile (make) which produces the executable. I then simply like to run and get the terminal output until it's closed.

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type":"node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch my app",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\myApp.exe",
      "args": [
        "-d",
        "-v",
        "-l",
        "debug.log"
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "make",
      "postDebugTask": "",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

While the tasks.json looks like this:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "make",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "make",
      "args": [],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "silent"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Sadly, VSCode always returns error

> Cannot launch program 'C:\Users\Volker\src\myApp\myApp.exe'; setting
>   the 'outFiles' attribute might help.

I examined using ProcessExplorer and no one even tries to run the executable :-(

How to run the executable after it was build?

Comment: Just a hunch: instead of F5, how about doing it manually. Go to the Debug panel, then select your launch config from the top dropdown, and then click on the Run button?

Comment: @GinoMempin I just tried, but it behaves exactly the same as with F5. It runs the same launch.json. Or did I miss something?